# Preventing Save-As (multiple conditions)

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to build a macro to prevent the Workbook being saved if several mandatory entries aren't completed.

For example in cell D14 the user should input 'yes' or 'no' - and there's a drop-down list to facilitate this. If the cell isn't filled in, the workbook can't be saved. I've achieved this with the following;

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D14")) Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "SAVE CANCELLED. Please ensure all mandatory entries are completed."
End If
End Sub
```

This is working fine.

The only issue is I want the file to open with D14 blank. One way around this is that D3 has to be filled in also, with a date. Is it possible to include something like 'if D3 is not empty, then D14 contains 'yes' or 'no' or it can't be saved'.

Or any other ideas as to how to open the file with the mandatory entries blank, but not save unless they are completed?

The mandatory entries are not limited to D14 - they include various cells in column D. But I can edit code to allow for that.

Thanks!

Comment: Just like you used `Workbook_BeforeSave`, you could use `Workbook_Open` to clear the interested cells when you open the workbook.
Anyway... The question is not really understandable and the title is IMHO misleading

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer posted by @Noldor130884 you can achieve what you want with the AND function in your IF statement

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D14")) AND Not IsEmpty(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("D3")) Then
Cancel = True
MsgBox "SAVE CANCELLED. Please ensure all mandatory entries are completed."
End If
End Sub
```

Obviously `Workbook_open` function to set the D3 and D14 values to NULL on open is an awesome solution. but the only risk is if you are referencing that value from some other file you will have the old values till you open the spreadsheet and you will not be able to save it due to your validation check.